# xmlstarlet - search attribute

Tags: xml, shell

given this xml as example:

```
<epp:phrases xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epp="http://eprints.org/ep3/phrase" xmlns:epc="http://eprints.org/ep3/control">
  <epp:phrase id="Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:title">Batch Editing Tool</epp:phrase>
  <epp:phrase id="Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:action:edit">Apply Actions</epp:phrase>
  <epp:phrase id="Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:edit_title">Modify Records</epp:phrase>
  <epp:phrase id="Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:remove_title">Remove all Records</epp:phrase>
  <epp:phrase id="Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:remove_help">Destroy all matching items. Once destroyed the items will be gone forever - this action <b>cannot be undone</b>!</epp:phrase>
  <epp:phrase id="Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:confirm_remove">Are you absolutely sure you want to destroy all these items (this action cannot be undone)?</epp:phrase>
</epp:phrases>
```

how i can use xmlstarlet to obtain the inner value searching the @id attribute?

so if i search "Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:remove_title" i want the text "Remove all Records"

other command line scripts you suggest me to use?
thank you

Comment: Does it work if you try my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
//epp:phrase[@id="Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:remove_title"]/text()
```

**Edit:**

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//epp:phrase[@id="Plugin/Screen/BatchEdit:remove_title"]/text()' x.xml
```

Comment: fine, it works, but need to specify the namespace:                    xml sel -N epp="http://eprints.org/ep3/phrase"